# Inline function filling an array

Tags: java, arrays, lambda

Is there any way to declare and populate an array in Java using an inline function/lambda like seen below?

```
final int NUM_NAMES = 10;
String names = () -> {
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_NAMES; i++) {
        names.add("Name " + i);
    }
    return names.toArray();
};
```

Comment: You can do something like that, as long as the target/declared type of the lambda expression is a functional interface (and not String as you have it). What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, NUM_NAMES).mapToObj(i -> "Name " + i).toArray(String[]::new)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
List<String> names = IntStream.range(0, 10)
    .boxed()
    .map(i -> String.format("Name %d", i))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Hopefully syntax is fine there but you get the idea.

Comment: No need to do the `boxed()`, just do `mapToObj(...)`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Then, however, there would be an auto-boxing at the expression `String.format("Name %d", i)`, which this approach circumvents. I guess it's a trade-off.

Comment: @Izruo it's not really about the boxing, it's more about not needing to box explicitly. (But you can avoid the boxing, ofc, by just doing straight concatenation `"name " + i`).

Answer (score 1):

You *technically can* do this inline, but the syntax is quite verbose:

```
String[] names = ((Supplier<String[]>)() -> {
  ArrayList<String> namesList = new ArrayList<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_NAMES; i++) {
    namesList.add("Name " + i);
  }
  return namesList.toArray(new String[0]);
}).get();
```

so I wouldn't recommend it. You would have to specify the type of the lambda expression, cast to that type, and then put the whole cast expression in brackets so that you can call `get` to get the array that is produced.

A more concise way to initialise arrays inline would be a helper method like this (this is inspired by Kotlin's array constructors):

```
public static <T> T[] buildArray(T[] arr, IntFunction<T> elementFunction) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++) {
      arr[i] = elementFunction.apply(i);
    }
    return arr;
}
```

In the second parameter, you specify what element you want for each index:

```
String[] names = buildArray(new String[NUM_NAMES], i -> "Name " + i);
```

Comment: Your `buildArray` method is how `Arrays.setAll` should have been implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the shortest way is to use [Arrays.setAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll(T%5B%5D,java.util.function.IntFunction)) which can be used to set values in arrays of any type, along with a index value generator to determine each indexed value:

```
String[] names = new String[NUM_NAMES];
Arrays.setAll(names, i -> "Name " + i);
```

Unfortunately `Arrays.setAll` does not return the array so you cannot put the whole declaration of `names` in one line.